# delete particular extension of files from a directory c++17 filesystem

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to delete particular extension of files from a given directory. I am using below way to do it. Is there any better way to do this in c++17?

```
std::string path = R"(C:\temp\)";
std::string ext(".txt");

for (const auto & folderIter : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
{
    std::cout << folderIter.path() << std::endl;
    if (folderIter.path().extension() == ext)
    {
        std::filesystem::remove(folderIter.path());
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Is there any better way to do this in c++17?"* In which context? performance, readability, line of code, ...?

Comment: I would say `std::filesystem::path` instead if `std::string` usage. Except that, it is fine for me.

Comment: @Jarod42 may be all aspects :)